# When you need a value type and inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, struct

I've run into a bit of a problem.

I need classes or structs to represent different types of vertices (`TextureVertex`, `ColorVertex`, etc). I also need a super class (`Vertex`) as I need to be able to make `VertexBuffer` for any vertex type. The vertices must be of value type, why I seem to need a struct.

How is this kind of conflicts usually solved in C#?

EDIT:
The reason I need value type data is that method (http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/m-sharpdx-direct3d11-buffer-create--1-1) seems to require it this way. It calls unmanaged code, and the vertex data goes in to the data parameter.

EDIT 2: Throwing out some code

```
public interface Vertex
{ }

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct TextureVertex : Vertex
{
    private Vector3 _position;
    public Vector3 Position { get { return _position; } set { _position = value; } }

    private Vector2 _texture;
    public Vector2 Texture { get { return _texture; } set { _texture = value; } }

    private Vector3 _normal;
    public Vector3 Normal { get { return _normal; } set { _normal = value; } }

    public TextureVertex(float x, float y, float z, float u, float v)
    {
        _position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
        _texture = new Vector2(u, v);
        _normal = new Vector3();
    }
}

...

TextureVertex[] vertices = new []
{
    new TextureVertex(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
    new TextureVertex(-1.0f, +1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
    new TextureVertex(+1.0f, +1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f),
    new TextureVertex(+1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)
};

...

VertexBuffer = Buffer.Create<Vertex>(Graphics.Device, BindFlags.VertexBuffer, vertices);
```

Comment: This seems not a [real question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question) to me. Did you try anything? Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Why do you need a "value type" for vertices?

Comment: Your question is **very** vague without code.

Comment: Sounds like you're giving us an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to solve.

Comment: What properties are you expecting each to have that are different from each other?

Comment: The different vertices will contain different data. All vertices contain a position vector. But a color vertex will contain a color value while a texture vertex will contain texture and normal coordinates.

Comment: I also need to have the data in the vertex objects sequential, which I guess again requires me to use structs in place of classes. (I use [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)].)

Comment: But would a vertex not be able to have a texture, normal, and colour value? It sounds like you'll have three vertex objects all pointing to the same point in space

Comment: @Sayse: Not all vertices use texturing for example. A textured vertex usually would not need a color either (unless you tint the texture for example).

Comment: so don't set a value for them?

Comment: @Sayse: As i commented on Eilistraee, one should keep the vertices as small as possible. The reason for this is that the number of vertices can quickly rise to many millions, and with them the load on the graphics memory.

Comment: I'm well aware of the load on graphics, but your making 3 vertex objects to point to the same vertex in space

Comment: @Sayse: No I'm not. This particular type of vertex does have position, texture and normal coordinates. A ColorVertex, for example, would not have all those.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That combination of requirements is not possible. You could make `Vertex` an interface (`IVertex`), but note that any `struct` that is then typed as `IVertex` will be "boxed". Perhaps your best bet is to use generics, i.e. `Buffer<T> where T : IVertex`. As long as you type any variables / fields / etc in terms of `T` (rather than `IVertex`) then it will be ***constrained***, which is to say: not boxed. The moment you use `IVertex` in the code (other than in the constraint) you will get boxing - so try to avoid that.

Specifically:

```
T[] someBuffer = ...

T item0 = someBuffer[0]; // no box required here
item0.SomeMethodOnIVertex(); // this is a "constrained" call; no boxing

IVertex item1 = someBuffer[1]; // BOX HERE!!!
item1.SomeMethodOnIVertex(); // this is a virtual call via the box
```

Comment: But I can't control Buffer. It's a class residing in the SharpDX assemblies.

Comment: @SamiHuutoniemi fine; then presumably it doesn't care about your own interface anyway, so shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: But I still have the problem of


Error: The type 'Vertex' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'SharpDX.Direct3D11.Buffer.Create<T>(SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device, SharpDX.Direct3D11.BindFlags, T[], int, SharpDX.Direct3D11.ResourceUsage, SharpDX.Direct3D11.CpuAccessFlags, SharpDX.Direct3D11.ResourceOptionFlags, int)'

Comment: @SamiHuutoniemi yes, which is why you should be specifying `TextureVertex` etc, not `Vertex`. You ***cannot*** treat different value-types as directly interchangeable. What you *would like* to do is simply not an option.

Comment: So in other words, you are saying I need specific versions of the method creating the VertexBuffer for every kind of Vertex?

Comment: @SamiHuutoniemi or (taking into account the context you added after I answered) you will need the "method creating the `VertexBuffer`" to itself be generic in `T`, with a `where T : struct` - then calling `... = Buffer.Create<T>(...);`. You could add the `IVertex` to that too (i.e. `where T : struct, IVertex`) if your code needs access to those features

Comment: This seems to work. I say seems as it does compile, but I'm a bit too far away from enough code to test it properly. I will mark the answer later, or add a follow up question! Thanks (all) for the discussions!

Comment: Generic types which are constrained to interfaces may have the interface methods used on them without boxing; structs which implement interfaces may thus be very performant.  Unfortunately, it's very easy to accidentally write code which will cause the compiler to perform operations on a copy of a struct rather than the original (whether because of boxing or some other reason), and there's no way a struct can specify (e.g. via attribute) that it when an operation can't be done on a struct instance the compiler should squawk rather than doing the operation on a copy.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use inheritance in this case.

The reason why vertex are value type is to make sure that an array of vertices (essentially a buffer) will be laid out as a chunk of consecutive memory.

This way, the underlying Framework will be able to copy it using only 1 operation when sending it to the graphic driver.

But this behavior of value types come with a big limiation indeed: All instances of Vertex MUST have the same size in memory, so that the runtime can locate a value in the array from its index.

But allowing inheritance on a struct would break this expectation, as you could put a ColorVertex (with Color data) in an Array of Vertex values, therefore having objects of different size in the same array.

This behavior is possible with ref types (think of 'class') because in this case the array will only store fixed size references  to the real content.

But it also means that copying only the array would not include the actual data, and copying the actual data would require reading the array, then copying each instance individually which would not yield acceptable performance for a 3D engine.

Comment: Yes! This is the problem indeed. And for the moment I don't see solutions beside putting all data in every vertex. But that is not very good either as one should keep the vertex buffers as small as possible.

Feels like a bad example in the code though as I have unused normal data in it, but in most cases normal data is actually used.

Comment: You should use different structs for each vertex type, and use them accordingly to your needs, each in different vertex buffers (and with different shaders). I don't see why you would want to have vertices with different content types in the same vertex buffer. (and your shader wouldn't know how to deal with that eitherway)

Comment: Oh, no I dont want to have different vertex types in the same shader. But I do want the class containing the vertex buffer, and the method creating the vertex buffer, to be able to handle a generic vertex, in place of one create method for every kind.

Comment: Oh, I understand. Then you could make the method generic, and probably decorate your structs with attributes to be able to extract the required metadata in order to configure your graphic pipeline. It will require a small amount of reflection, and doing it right really depend upon the flexibility level you want to achieve (vs the simplicity of use).